# Is there a value for the Sprint Boot @ConfigurationProperties compatible with both Eclipse IDE and InteliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, intellij-idea, compatibility, properties-file

Having a simple Sprint Boot application with the health actuator endpoint enables, allows you to specify and bind such a property in `application.properties` (in one of the following accepted ways):

```
# Eclipse IDE
management.endpoint.health.show-details=when-authorized
# or
# InteliJ IDEA
management.endpoint.health.show-details=when_authorized
```

The value of this property is one of an Enum type.

Both variants are accepted because of the [Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) feature of Spring Boot `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations.

While both values are valid from Spring and Maven build point of view, each of the two IDEs will only suggest (auto-completion, hover-documentation, ctrl-click-navigate-to-definition) their own version of value of the property and report an error if the other one is used.

Is there a way to make both world happy?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue in IDEA. Please vote/follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171730

Answer (score 0):

Found a version that makes everyone (almost) happy (Maven, InteliJ IDEA, Eclipse):

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=WHEN_AUTHORIZED
```

The Spring Boot implementation defines it like this and using this form, almost everyone is happy.

Eclipse IDE
* if you type "W", the auto-completion will follow capitalised
* both hover documentation and code navigation work

InteliJ IDEA
* auto-completion **will never suggest** the capitalised version (but it will not show an error when using it)
* both hover documentation and code navigation work

and Maven does not care since Spring Boot is using the relaxed binding rules here.